# Case insensitive partition under Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, filenames, case-sensitivity

Is there a way to format and use a partition under Linux which is case-insensitive?

I know of vfat, but was hoping I could find some alternatives. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JFS with Option -O:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.jfs

CIOPFS (case insensitive on purpose file system):

http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/

Answer (score 3):

You can create case insensitive filesystems with ZFS:

```
# zfs create -o casesensitivity=insensitive filesystem
```

Comment: ZFS is distributed with Sun CDDL license, which is incompatible with GPL license used by Linux Kernel. So, ZFS cannot be (legally) used with Linux. The only option is to use ZFS with filesystem in userspace (zfs-fuse).

Comment: ZFS on fuse is quite usable. I'm sharing pools between ubuntu and Solaris with no issues. There are also native ZFS projects: http://zfsonlinux.org/ https://github.com/zfs-linux

Comment: this is probably the best solution. As of now ZFS has been distributed with Ubuntu for years

Answer (score 1):

- Gabriel Krisman Bertazi (who is the author of the [case-insentive feature in ext4](https://lwn.net/Articles/784041/)) wrote the blog [Using the Linux kernel's Case-insensitive feature in Ext4](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2020/08/27/using-the-linux-kernel-case-insensitive-feature-in-ext4/). In short you need to enable the [`casefold`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) [property](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/mke2fs.8.html)

  ```
  mkfs -t ext4 -O casefold /dev/vda
  ```

  For existing filesystems:

  ```
  tune2fs -O casefold /dev/sda1
  ```

  This doesn't automatically make the *whole* filesystem case-insensitive – each directory has to be marked so individually:

  ```
  chattr +F ~/.wine
  ```
- F2FS also supports case-insensitive name lookups via the [`casefold` option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/mkfs.f2fs.8.html)

  ```
  mkfs.f2fs -O casefold /dev/hda
  ```
- XFS supports case-insensitive ASCII file names through the [`version=ci`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.xfs) option

  ```
  mkfs.xfs -f -n version=ci /dev/sda
  ```

For more information read https://lwn.net/Kernel/Index/#Filesystems-Case-independent_lookups